# How to rebuild the object with repr?

Tags: python, representation, repr

My code works perfectly except the last part. I want to recreate the object with repr function but it clearly doesn't work. I tried everything here and on the web but i'm still so confuse. Is there any way to do it and if so what is the syntax ?

```
class Modulo(object):

    def __init__(self, grondtal, waarde = 0):
        self.grondtal = grondtal
        self.waarde = waarde % grondtal

    def __call__(self, m):
        return Modulo(self.grondtal, m)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Modulo(self.grondtal, self.waarde + other.waarde)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Modulo(self.grondtal, self.waarde - other.waarde)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Modulo(self.grondtal, self.waarde * other.waarde)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.waarde == other.waarde and self.grondtal == other.grondtal

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __str__(self):
        return  '[%s %% %s]' % (str(self.grondtal), str(self.waarde))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s' %Modulo(self.grondtal, self.waarde)
```

Comment: `return '%s, %s' % (self.grondtal, self.waarde)`

Comment: Looks like you want `return 'Modulo(%s, %s)' % (self.grondtal, self.waarde)`.

Comment: @ChristianDean when i run yours then i get:
 'tuple' object has no attribute 'waarde'

Comment: @Matthias I have string representation of my object and i want to rebuild the object with eval function that's all.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad That's a _bad, bad_ idea. Do _not_ use `eval`, ever!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Modulo(%d,%d)" % (self.grondtal, self.waarde)
```

Or, a little bit more generic:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "%s(%d,%d)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.grondtal, self.waarde)
```

For example:

```
>>> m = Modulo(3,2)
>>> repr(m)
'Modulo(3,2)'
```